# Why is the Quran so hard against those who questioned the prophet?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, hell

There are obnoxious people like Abu Lahab and Uqba Mu'ayt who lived during Muhammad's(pbuh) lifetime . They were skeptical of the prophet, got physical at him, and threw excrement at his house. They were hated people and died painful deaths. But why does things have to get so personal that Quran should mention them by name as the inhabitants of Hell, and describe what would be done specifically to them. Shouldn't the Qur'an and the prophet be beyond these insults and simply ignore these clowns. Why don't we just get over these people?

Comment: can you provide references?

Answer (score 1):

If God Ignores such clowns no one would ever remember them and would continue to do same bad deeds. If God gives people example of past events and warns them that if you did similar you might get same punishment this stops other to repeat same bad deeds at least they would think before they leap.

This is same as a child learns from his parents. If he is not stopped/scolded he continues or else he learns from experience which gets painful most of the times.